# How to set up magento project locally

Tags: magento2, localhost, domain, download

For example, there is project at **www.example.com**

How can I download this project and edit it on **localhost**.
I am using **nginx**.

Can someone explain to me what I have to do step by step!?

Comment: please google this

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below steps to setup local magento instance by using existing code base.

- Download entire code base from server and copy to your local xampp / wamp document root ( C:/xampp/htdocs/xyz )
- Download the DB dump from remote server and import into your local mysql database ( phpmyadmin )
- Change the secure & unsecure base url from http://www.example.com into http://localhost/xyz/ in core_config_data table
- Change the database connection details ( hostname, dbname, username and password ) in app/etc/config.php file
- Give 777  permission on var/ , pub/ folder
- Clear cache folders ( var/cache, var/page_cache, var/di, var/generation )
- You have to ensure mod_rewrite is enabled in your apache config
- You have to ensure "symlinks options" are enabled in your apache folder